# how to limit loop in assembly x86(printing infinitly)?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .data
msg db 'hello world',10,0

section .text
global main

extern printf

main: 
    mov ecx,5
    lable1:
        push msg
        call printf
        add esp,4
        loop lable1 
    ret
;;------------------------------------sample program--------------------------

section .data
val dd 20
msg db 'number is : %d',10,0    

section .text
global main

extern printf

main: 
    mov ecx,5
    lable1:
        inc dword[val]
        loop lable1
    push dword[val]
    push msg
    call printf
    add esp,8   
ret
```

Comment: Learn a bit more assembly. What you want to do is a conditional jump, so learn up to that part.

Comment: i can do using condtional jump

Comment: Fine, then do it. Or you're implying something that is not in your question, then edit your question with more info.

Comment: why sample program not going in infinite state ? there also i havnt used conditional jump.  Doing with counter reg.  ecx only (read edited)

Answer (score 0):

`loop` decrements `ecx` and performs the jump if `ecx` is not zero after the decrement. The problem in your first program is that you're calling `printf` in the body of the loop, which is very likely to overwrite `ecx`.

You should save the value of `ecx` prior to calling `printf()`, and then restore it again prior to your `loop` instruction.

Comment: i dont want to run infinitly i want to terminate after 5 times in both programs.          But it only happens in second program.  whats wrong in 1st program?

Comment: And which one doesn't terminate after 5 times?

Comment: first program which prints "hello world"

Comment: @matheromqq: As I said in my original answer, `printf()` is very likely to be trashing `ecx`. You'll need to save its value.

Comment: replced lop body as ---replace---    now working .why printf overwrites ecx?

Comment: @matheromqq: Because it uses `ecx`. If another function called the one you are currently writing, your function would overwrite `ecx` too. You only have a limited number of registers to use. You have to follow the relevant calling conventions when using assembly, and be aware - among other things - of which registers you have to preserve in your own function, and which registers will not be preserved by any functions you call.